# Chaining functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-got

I am currently trying to use the *got* module https://www.npmjs.com/package/got but I am a bit confused on the format/order of functions. It's evident that you can chain the listeners and functions as such

```
 got.stream(link)
 .on('response', resp => {
   if (resp.statusCode != 200) this.emit('error', '!200')
 })
 .on('error', err => {
   console.log(err)
 })
 .pipe(somewhere)
```

The [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module also does this. But how do you avoid `.pipe` if you want it to happen only on the condition `resp.statusCode != 200`? Seeing that it's used in a lot of request modules, it must be a very basic thing to understand but I can't quite grasp it.

Comment: When you do `got.stream(whatever)`, it is generating a "Readable Stream", which is basically something which emits data in chunks, rather than all at once like just returning everything at once like a normal function or whatever. You can see the documentation for readable streams here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams

Comment: Right - but is there a way to not start piping until the condition is met? Or is that not possible in this case? [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch) seems to be able to do this by being able to assign the stream to a variable, and having `this` in the listener being able to pipe whenever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* to chain it if you don't want to, and in this situation, you don't want to. Here's a simplified example of you'd do it without chaining:

```
const gotStream = got.stream(link);
gotStream.on('response', resp => {
    if(resp.statusCode == 200) {
        gotStream.pipe(somewhere);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah I see now. I had tried this before posting the question but instead I was using `got(link)` and trying to pipe that instead. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help! If this fully answers your question, you can click the check under the vote counter to "accept" this answer as the correct one.